# Show just the necessary div when user clicks on a targeted div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to slidetoggle a div, when the target div is clicked. I am trying to manipulate all the divs with just one function and I'm trying to use the same classes.

But when I click on say, div1 - divA slidetoggles and after if I click div2 - divB slidetoggles below divA.

What I want to achieve is to show just the necessary div when user clicks on a targeted div.

Here is what I've done so far: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/cFR4U/#base)

My js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(function(){
        $('.divshow').click(function(){
            $('.services-info').hide();
            $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();
        });
    });
});
```

repeating markup:

```
<div class="horiz">
         <div class="webserv1 divshow" target="a">
             <h4 class="namesss">Lorem</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="webserv2 divshow" target="b">
            <h4 class="namesss">Ipsum</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="webserv3 divshow" target="c">
            <h4 class="namesss">Dolor</h4>
         </div>
       </div>

    <!-- Hidden info boxes1 start-->
    <div class="service-info" id="diva">
        <p>Lorem1 ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service-info" id="divb">
        <p>Lorem2 ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service-info" id="divc">
        <p>Lorem3 ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Hidden info boxes1 end-->
```

and some part of my css:

```
.service-info {
display:none;
position:relative;
float:left;
width:300px;
height:100px;
background-color:#a5a2a2;
color:#fff;
padding:3%;
border-radius:5px;
border:2px solid #dbdbdb;
}
```

How can I hide any other divs when a div becomes visible?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution did not worked because you have used incorrect class selector to hide the element. also you need to use `.not()` to prevent hide for currently clicked elements target div:

```
 $('.divshow').click(function(){
                $('.service-info').not('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).hide();
            $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();
        });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JmGL6/)**

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! By the way, how can I make the transition between two click more smooth?

Comment: @EkinHazal: you can use `.slideUp()` instead of `.hide()`. see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/7yCMJ/

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

keep track of the opened div and 'toggle it back'.

```
var tg=false;

$(document).ready( function() {
        $(function(){
            $('.divshow').click(function(){
            if(tg!==false && $(this).not(tg))$('#div'+$(tg).attr('target')).slideToggle();
            $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();
            tg=$(this);
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cFR4U/8/)

Comment: Hey thanks, yet it's not closing when you click twice to a div.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that :-) Updated the answer and the fiddle.